# Is it possible to export your Netflix queue?

Tags: rss, netflix

I'm about to cancel my Netflix account and I'd like to be able to keep the list of movies in my queue.  Is there an easy way to export the list in plain text so I don't have to resort to printing it out?

Comment: How many movies are in your queue?

Comment: 320 movies.

Comment: Why not, just copy and paste the que or save the html file to your desktop?

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a web service. It would be on topic for [webapps.se], but this question is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got something very basic working by:

- Saving the source of my queue page
- Putting a link to Google-hosted jQuery in the `<head>` of the document and removing some of the existing JS.  Like so:

  `<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>`
   `<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>`
- Loading the local page in Firefox
- Running this code in the Firebug console:

  `$('span.title a').each(function(index) {`
      `console.log($(this).html());`
  `});`

That just spit out the titles of everything in my queue.

Comment: Nice use of JQuery -- the nice thing about my way is it works for *any* RSS feed -- and doesn't require Firebug, saving locally, or a working knowledge of JQuery.

Comment: I agree, your solution is much nicer, but I can't get all 320 items.

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: $("span.title a") is null`

Answer (score 20):

**Using Google Docs + Netflix RSS to pull up to 250 items in your queue (or other things!)**

- Login to Netflix
- Click RSS at the bottom of the page (hint, its nessled between some other junk):

> Jobs  Media Center Netflix Prize  **RSS**  App Gallery  Facebook Connect Tell a Friend

- Get the RSS feed for your queue:

> Personalized Feeds
>
> *Queue: http://rss.netflix.com/QueueRSS?id=P191900XXXXX892`*

- Load up Google Docs, open a new spreadsheet, goto A1 and enter:

> =importfeed("**URLFROMABOVE**",,true,250)

Note the *double quotes* around the URL.  The `true` pulls in column headers and the max queue entries supported by Google is 250.

You should now have a Google docs spreadsheet with your queue in it with `TITLE`, `URL`, and `DESCRIPTION` headers.  Use it as you will.

- If you don't want the 001- part.. create a new cell with this formula (in Google docs):

> =right(A2,len(A2)-5)

Which will cut off the 001- part (if 001- is in A2).  Just copy the formula down to get the rest of the title's sans the ID.

**Link to my Example**

Link to my girlfriends (don't tell her im sharing!): http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Al6h7KQIZVQFdEI2aXJfeGhZSWNhdjczY1pQV2JOSHc&hl=en

**Image of result**

[image]

> 

**(attempt #2) Less Elegant, but returns entire QUEUE:**

> 

- Grab your RSS URL (see above).
- Goto `http://pipes.yahoo.com/earth2marsh/feed2csv`
- Enter your RSS url from above into the `URL` box and click `Run Pipe`.
- Right click 'get as RSS' and copy the URL.
- Load Google docs, open a new file, and enter:

> = importdata("`url copied above`")

- Before you click OK, find the part in the url that says `render=rss`

> .......pipe.run?_id=49c30ca389410df9ef49b008e0d65203&**_render=rss**&feedURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.go...........

and change it to render=csv

- See the examlpe Google document below, check the second tab at the bottom labeled `IMPORTDATA`

or .. just copy the URL, change to render=csv, and save the sucker and open locally in Excel.  Poo on Google for ruining my pretty answer.

[CSV FILE](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Al6h7KQIZVQFdEI2aXJfeGhZSWNhdjczY1pQV2JOSHc&hl=en) of my girlfriends netflix.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution, but it only returns the first 21 items.

Comment: Of course; the docs don't mention this limitation at all...
http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75507

Comment: I just tried this in Excel 2010 and it works exactly the same. I just clicked "File / Open" and pasted the queue URL in, and answered a few simple xml questions and got my queue right in Excel. So +1 for using a spreadsheet + RSS to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like Netflix removed the RSS feature.

Comment: As of April 2014, the RSS feeds are working again. My DVD queue RSS looks like this: http://dvd.netflix.com/QueueRSS?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

After failing at the above suggestions several times, I just opened my Netflix RSS, went to File/Save As.  it defaulted to .xml and saved it to the desktop.  Then I opened it up in Excel.  Got a lovely little spreadsheet that was ready to edit, sort, and delete unneeded columns.  The entire 375 item queue was available in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above seemed to work for me so I tried something else.

I opened Internet Explorer 9, logged into Netflix, went to my queue, and right clicked the page. There was an option to "Export to Microsoft Excel" which when clicked opens Excel. Copy the address of the Netflix queue you would like to save, paste in Excel "address" bar, and click "Go."Go ahead and click "Import" and wait for Excel to import the data. Once finished, click "OK" on the Import Data window to import into the existing sheet, then delete any unnecessary rows and columns.

Comment: Works in IE 8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://ratings-exporter.heroku.com/

Uses the Netflix API. It can't export all of your ratings. Only those movies that you have in your rental history.

update: if you want access to the code, it's on github @ https://github.com/sorens/ratings-exporter

Comment: service is now disabled

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your browser I can't give specifics but try saving the page to disk.  If that doesn't work for you, right-click and pick "view source" and use that.

Answer (score 0):

If using Chrome, check out the Flix Plus by Lifehacker extension (http://lifehacker.com/flix-plus-customizes-netflix-to-your-hearts-desire-1640968001) that I wrote which lets you export your My List to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the missing rss feature I also had to make use of jQuery. The following snippets run on the "My Activity" page return 3 newline separated lists which can be easily copied into a spreadsheet document. Nothing else than a browser with a javascript console should be needed.

**list of dates**

```
jQuery.map(jQuery.find('.retable .date'), function(element) { return jQuery(element).text(); }).join("\n")
```

**list of names**

```
jQuery.map(jQuery.find('.retable a:not(.reportLink):not(.deleteBtn)'), function(element) { return jQuery(element).text(); }).join("\n")
```

**list of hrefs**

```
jQuery.map(jQuery.find('.retable a:not(.reportLink):not(.deleteBtn)'), function(element) { return element.href; }).join("\n")
```